# C - How to solve "Address is 0 bytes after a block of size alloc'd"

Tags: c, valgrind

Need help with my code. I run the program with valgrind and got errors: 
"Address 0x520448a is 0 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd". This code get words from a file and save each word to a struct that have the properties `char *word` and int `line_number`:

```
void process_file_words(FILE *exist_file, struct file_word *file_words){
    enum status {IN, OUT};
    int i, c, next_char;
    int prev_char = '\0';
    int line_number = 1;
    int j = 0;
    size_t size = 10;
    int state = OUT;
    bool in_decimal_number = false;

    /* get all words in the file using fgetc */
    for(;;) {
        c = fgetc(exist_file);
        if ( feof(exist_file) ){
            break;
        }
        next_char = fgetc(exist_file);
        /* Move the file position back to it's original position */
        if ( next_char != EOF ) {
            fseek(exist_file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        /* Check if we are in a middle of a decimal number */
        if ( c == '.' ) {
            if ( isdigit(next_char) && prev_char && isdigit(prev_char) ) {
                in_decimal_number = true;
            }
        } else if ( c == '\n' ) {
            line_number++;
        }
        /* If we are outside of a word, create new word */
        if ( (isalpha(c) || isdigit(c)) && state == OUT ) {
            /* increase the words count as we have a new word */
            words_count_index++;
            /* allocate memory for the new word */
            file_words[words_count_index].word = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
            assert(file_words[words_count_index].word);
            file_words[words_count_index].word[j++] = (char) c;
            file_words[words_count_index].line_number = line_number;
            state = IN;
        } else if ( (isalpha(c) || isdigit(c) || in_decimal_number) && state == IN ) {
            /* check if more memory is needed */
            if ( j == size ) {
                if ( (file_words[words_count_index].word = realloc(file_words[words_count_index].word, (size *= 2) * sizeof(char))) == NULL ) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error trying to reallocate memory.\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            file_words[words_count_index].word[j++] = (char) c;
        } else {
            /* we are outside of a word, reset variables */
            state = OUT;
            j = 0;
            size = 10;
        }

        if ( in_decimal_number ) {
            in_decimal_number = false;
        }
        prev_char = c;
    }

    /* save exact words count to a variable */
    words_count = words_count_index + 1;

    /* null-terminate the words array */
    for ( i = 0; i < words_count; i++ ) {
        size_t word_len = strlen(file_words[i].word);
        file_words[i].word[word_len+1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

\

```
==19981== Invalid read of size 1
==19981==    at 0x4C30F74: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19981==    by 0x401330: process_file_words (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
==19981==    by 0x400C3C: main (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
==19981==  Address 0x520448a is 0 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
==19981==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19981==    by 0x40112D: process_file_words (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
==19981==    by 0x400C3C: main (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
==19981== 
==19981== Invalid write of size 1
==19981==    at 0x401357: process_file_words (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
==19981==    by 0x400C3C: main (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
==19981==  Address 0x520448b is 1 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
==19981==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19981==    by 0x40112D: process_file_words (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
==19981==    by 0x400C3C: main (in /home/avishay/Desktop/haptoha-C/maman23/myprog)
```

I searched for answers in the web and this error seems to be related to the fact that the allocated memory is not null-terminated. However I did null-terminate the memory at the end of the function.

Comment: It means that strlen is reading past the end of allocated storage. Why could that be?

Comment: I assume `FOREVER` is a macro for `for (;;)` or `while (1)`.

Comment: why the down votes?

Comment: You null terminate the string after you read the length with strlen!? strlen actually needs a null terminated string to determine the length!

Comment: `FOREVER` is 7 letters and `while(1)` is 8. What did you gain by saving that half second while you traded in readability?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya It just more understandable and pleasing to the human eye to read "forever" rather then "while(1)". I did edit the question so you will understand it.

Comment: You people need to stop being sarcastic, what ever is trivial to you is not always trivial to someone who has just started learning the language. This is the whole idea of asking questions. I still don't see why this question got 3 down votes.

Comment: @Avishay28 the only audience likely to read your C source code are (apart from machines/compilers) people who understand C. These people will *know* what `while (0)` or `for (;;)` means, but `FOREVER` is just irritating.

Comment: @Avishay28 as for the downvotes: not mine but still easy to explain -- 1.) your code is by no means *minimal* for reproducing the problem, 2.) the solution to this problem can be found in many FAQs, including the links provided in the C tag description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code near the end:

```
size_t word_len = strlen(file_words[i].word);
file_words[i].word[word_len+1] = '\0';
```

makes no sense. The entire *point* of `strlen()` is to look for the string termination, so using it in order to compute where to put the termination is illogical.

It also includes an off-by-one error, but that's of course redundant.

You must terminate the string as you build it, since only then do you know its length. Also remember to allocate space for the termination character.

Comment: I removed the `stlern()` and null-terminate while building the string, however the second error still appears. Any idea why?